# Laravel Cashier Stripe Webhooks not working. Unable to trigger events via "stripe trigger" and react to them in Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-9, laravel-cashier

I am trying to set up a Subscription Feature in my Laravel Application.

As stated in the Laravel Cashier Docs, I created a webhook route, see first route in the group:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified', 'frontendOnly'])->group(function () {

    Route::post('stripe/webhooks', [App\Http\Controllers\StripeWebhookController::class, 'handleWebhook'])->name('stripe.webhook');
    Route::post('payment/store', [App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController::class, 'store'])->name('front.payment.store');
    Route::post('payment/validate', [App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController::class, 'paymentValidation'])->name('front.payment.validate');
    Route::post('payment/capture', [App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController::class, 'captureOrder'])->name('front.payment.capture');
    Route::post('payment/create/intent', [App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController::class, 'createIntent'])->name('front.payment.intent');
    Route::get('front/payment', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontPageController::class, 'payment'])->name('front.payment');

    Route::middleware(['payment'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('front/vacancy/{vacancy}', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontPageController::class, 'vacancy'])->name('front.vacancy');
        Route::get('front/compare', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontPageController::class, 'compare'])->name('front.compare');
        Route::post('front/application', [App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController::class, 'store'])->name('application.apply');
        Route::get('front/application', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontPageController::class, 'application'])->name('my.application');
        Route::get('front/subscription', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontPageController::class, 'subscription'])->name('subscription');
    });
});
```

Also, I created a controller (StripeWebhookController), which looks like this:

```
    class StripeWebhookController extends CashierController
{
    public function handleCustomerSubscriptionUpdated($payload)
    {
        dd('subscription updated', $payload);
    }

    public function handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted($payload)
    {
    }

    public function handleCustomerSubscriptionCreated($payload)
    {
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

    public function handleCustomerUpdated(array $payload)
    {
    }

    public function handleCustomerDeleted(array $payload)
    {
    }

    public function handleCustomerCreated(array $payload)
    {
    }

    public function handleChargeSucceeded(array $payload)
    {
    }

    public function handleChargeRefunded(array $payload)
    {
    }
}
```

And the CashierController comes from

```
 use Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController as CashierController;


and looks like:

    class WebhookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new WebhookController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (config('cashier.webhook.secret')) {
            $this->middleware(VerifyWebhookSignature::class);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle a Stripe webhook call.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleWebhook(Request $request)
    {
        $payload = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $method = 'handle' . Str::studly(str_replace('.', '_', $payload['type']));

        WebhookReceived::dispatch($payload);

        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            $this->setMaxNetworkRetries();

            $response = $this->{$method}($payload);

            WebhookHandled::dispatch($payload);

            return $response;
        }

        return $this->missingMethod($payload);
    }

    /**
     * Handle customer subscription created.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleCustomerSubscriptionCreated(array $payload)
    {
        $user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['customer']);

        if ($user) {
            $data = $payload['data']['object'];

            if (!$user->subscriptions->contains('stripe_id', $data['id'])) {
                if (isset($data['trial_end'])) {
                    $trialEndsAt = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($data['trial_end']);
                } else {
                    $trialEndsAt = null;
                }

                $firstItem = $data['items']['data'][0];
                $isSinglePrice = count($data['items']['data']) === 1;

                $subscription = $user->subscriptions()->create([
                    'name' => $data['metadata']['name'] ?? $this->newSubscriptionName($payload),
                    'stripe_id' => $data['id'],
                    'stripe_status' => $data['status'],
                    'stripe_price' => $isSinglePrice ? $firstItem['price']['id'] : null,
                    'quantity' => $isSinglePrice && isset($firstItem['quantity']) ? $firstItem['quantity'] : null,
                    'trial_ends_at' => $trialEndsAt,
                    'ends_at' => null,
                ]);

                foreach ($data['items']['data'] as $item) {
                    $subscription->items()->create([
                        'stripe_id' => $item['id'],
                        'stripe_product' => $item['price']['product'],
                        'stripe_price' => $item['price']['id'],
                        'quantity' => $item['quantity'] ?? null,
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->successMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Determines the name that should be used when new subscriptions are created from the Stripe dashboard.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return string
     */
    public function newSubscriptionName(array $payload)
    {
        return 'default';
    }

    /**
     * Handle customer subscription updated.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleCustomerSubscriptionUpdated(array $payload)
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['customer'])) {
            $data = $payload['data']['object'];

            $subscription = $user->subscriptions()->firstOrNew(['stripe_id' => $data['id']]);

            if (
                isset($data['status']) &&
                $data['status'] === StripeSubscription::STATUS_INCOMPLETE_EXPIRED
            ) {
                $subscription->items()->delete();
                $subscription->delete();

                return;
            }

            $subscription->name = $subscription->name ?? $data['metadata']['name'] ?? $this->newSubscriptionName($payload);

            $firstItem = $data['items']['data'][0];
            $isSinglePrice = count($data['items']['data']) === 1;

            // Price...
            $subscription->stripe_price = $isSinglePrice ? $firstItem['price']['id'] : null;

            // Quantity...
            $subscription->quantity = $isSinglePrice && isset($firstItem['quantity']) ? $firstItem['quantity'] : null;

            // Trial ending date...
            if (isset($data['trial_end'])) {
                $trialEnd = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($data['trial_end']);

                if (!$subscription->trial_ends_at || $subscription->trial_ends_at->ne($trialEnd)) {
                    $subscription->trial_ends_at = $trialEnd;
                }
            }

            // Cancellation date...
            if (isset($data['cancel_at_period_end'])) {
                if ($data['cancel_at_period_end']) {
                    $subscription->ends_at = $subscription->onTrial()
                        ? $subscription->trial_ends_at
                        : Carbon::createFromTimestamp($data['current_period_end']);
                } elseif (isset($data['cancel_at'])) {
                    $subscription->ends_at = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($data['cancel_at']);
                } else {
                    $subscription->ends_at = null;
                }
            }

            // Status...
            if (isset($data['status'])) {
                $subscription->stripe_status = $data['status'];
            }

            $subscription->save();

            // Update subscription items...
            if (isset($data['items'])) {
                $prices = [];

                foreach ($data['items']['data'] as $item) {
                    $prices[] = $item['price']['id'];

                    $subscription->items()->updateOrCreate([
                        'stripe_id' => $item['id'],
                    ], [
                        'stripe_product' => $item['price']['product'],
                        'stripe_price' => $item['price']['id'],
                        'quantity' => $item['quantity'] ?? null,
                    ]);
                }

                // Delete items that aren't attached to the subscription anymore...
                $subscription->items()->whereNotIn('stripe_price', $prices)->delete();
            }
        }

        return $this->successMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Handle a canceled customer from a Stripe subscription.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted(array $payload)
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['customer'])) {
            $user->subscriptions->filter(function ($subscription) use ($payload) {
                return $subscription->stripe_id === $payload['data']['object']['id'];
            })->each(function ($subscription) {
                $subscription->markAsCanceled();
            });
        }

        return $this->successMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Handle customer updated.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleCustomerUpdated(array $payload)
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['id'])) {
            $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethodFromStripe();
        }

        return $this->successMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Handle deleted customer.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleCustomerDeleted(array $payload)
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['id'])) {
            $user->subscriptions->each(function (Subscription $subscription) {
                $subscription->skipTrial()->markAsCanceled();
            });

            $user->forceFill([
                'stripe_id' => null,
                'trial_ends_at' => null,
                'pm_type' => null,
                'pm_last_four' => null,
            ])->save();
        }

        return $this->successMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Handle payment action required for invoice.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleInvoicePaymentActionRequired(array $payload)
    {
        if (is_null($notification = config('cashier.payment_notification'))) {
            return $this->successMethod();
        }

        if ($user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['customer'])) {
            if (in_array(Notifiable::class, class_uses_recursive($user))) {
                $payment = new Payment($user->stripe()->paymentIntents->retrieve(
                    $payload['data']['object']['payment_intent']
                ));

                $user->notify(new $notification($payment));
            }
        }

        return $this->successMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Get the customer instance by Stripe ID.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $stripeId
     * @return \Laravel\Cashier\Billable|null
     */
    public function getUserByStripeId($stripeId)
    {
        return Cashier::findBillable($stripeId);
    }

    /**
     * Handle successful calls on the controller.
     *
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function successMethod($parameters = [])
    {
        return new Response('Webhook Handled', 200);
    }

    /**
     * Handle calls to missing methods on the controller.
     *
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function missingMethod($parameters = [])
    {
        return new Response;
    }

    /**
     * Set the number of automatic retries due to an object lock timeout from Stripe.
     *
     * @param  int  $retries
     * @return void
     */
    public function setMaxNetworkRetries($retries = 3)
    {
        Stripe::setMaxNetworkRetries($retries);
    }
}
```

Via `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks` I listen to stripe events and via `stripe trigger customer.subscription.updated` I trigger for example the customer_subscription_updated event, and due to this, the function `handleCustomerSubscriptionUpdated`  in the `StripeWebhookController` should be called and `dd('subscription updated', $payload);`
Unfortunately, nothing happens in the Laravel app when I trigger an event.
After triggering, I can see that the trigger succeeded:

```
`Setting up fixture for: customer
Running fixture for: customer
Setting up fixture for: product
Running fixture for: product
Setting up fixture for: price
Running fixture for: price
Setting up fixture for: subscription
Running fixture for: subscription
Setting up fixture for: subscription_updated
Running fixture for: subscription_updated
Trigger succeeded! Check dashboard for event details.`
```

And In my listening terminal, I can see something like this:

```
2022-12-02 05:21:23   --> payment_method.attached [evt_1MAQkZLCBVZyRws5KhhmrZrb]
2022-12-02 05:21:23   --> customer.created [evt_1MAQkZLCBVZyRws5r4IBCMoh]
2022-12-02 05:21:23   --> product.created [evt_1MAQkaLCBVZyRws5anPfEA1h]
2022-12-02 05:21:23  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkZLCBVZyRws5KhhmrZrb]
2022-12-02 05:21:23  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkZLCBVZyRws5r4IBCMoh]
2022-12-02 05:21:23   --> plan.created [evt_1MAQkaLCBVZyRws5FGIB5eYU]
2022-12-02 05:21:23   --> price.created [evt_1MAQkaLCBVZyRws5Phd7ffQd]
2022-12-02 05:21:24  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkaLCBVZyRws5anPfEA1h]
2022-12-02 05:21:24  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkaLCBVZyRws5FGIB5eYU]
2022-12-02 05:21:24  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkaLCBVZyRws5Phd7ffQd]
2022-12-02 05:21:26   --> customer.updated [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5kWpF7YA2]
2022-12-02 05:21:27   --> invoice.created [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5wIOOT9KZ]
2022-12-02 05:21:27   --> invoice.finalized [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5S4wirUSb]
2022-12-02 05:21:27   --> invoice.paid [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5eMnSf5mo]
2022-12-02 05:21:27   --> invoice.payment_succeeded [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5EMMHcORP]
2022-12-02 05:21:27  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5kWpF7YA2]
2022-12-02 05:21:27   --> customer.subscription.created [evt_1MAQkeLCBVZyRws5Fdwc0j38]
2022-12-02 05:21:27   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3MAQkbLCBVZyRws51Xfs0nAt]
2022-12-02 05:21:27   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3MAQkbLCBVZyRws51dsCWItO]
2022-12-02 05:21:27  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5wIOOT9KZ]
2022-12-02 05:21:27   --> customer.subscription.updated [evt_1MAQkeLCBVZyRws52OksmPCZ]
2022-12-02 05:21:27  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5S4wirUSb]
2022-12-02 05:21:28  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5eMnSf5mo]
2022-12-02 05:21:28  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkdLCBVZyRws5EMMHcORP]
2022-12-02 05:21:28  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkeLCBVZyRws5Fdwc0j38]
2022-12-02 05:21:28  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_3MAQkbLCBVZyRws51Xfs0nAt]
2022-12-02 05:21:29  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_3MAQkbLCBVZyRws51dsCWItO]
2022-12-02 05:21:29  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1MAQkeLCBVZyRws52OksmPCZ]
2022-12-02 05:21:30   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3MAQkbLCBVZyRws51fn6Qdmf]
2022-12-02 05:21:31  <--  [302] POST http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks [evt_3MAQkbLCBVZyRws51fn6Qdmf]
```

As you can see, something happened, however my controller method didn't run and I did not get a 200er, but a 302. Does anybody know they reason? After 10 hours, I do not know what else to do. I have done everything as stated in the docs.

Thanks a lot for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Based on symfony's [code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L217), the default status code of a Response is 200, which mean both `successMethod` and `missingMethod` will return 200.

You might want to do search in your project with keywords `new Response` and `302` and see if there are any code that returns a 302 response.

Comment: Hello @qichuan,
Thanks for your answer. In the WebhookController, the two methods look like this:

`public function successMethod($parameters = [])
    {
        return new Response('Webhook Handled', 200);
    }`
 
and 

`public function missingMethod($parameters = [])
    {
        return new Response();
    }`
 so there is no 302 Error in there. Do you think because of the 302 (redirect) nothing happens in my laravel app?
Thx :)